# looking for a simple .net animation library

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, animation

I'd like to create a WinForms application that enables users to create very simple 2D animations. These keyframe based animations can contain simple objects, mainly some circles that will move frame by frame as the user defined. I'd like to also make it enable to export frames as images or the whole animations as video files.

I am an experienced c# .net developer, but I have never created apps like this. I looked around and most of the developers use some XNA, WPF, DirectX or opengl to create animations. In my case I feel all of them 'overkill', they are too complex for such a simple task, like mine.

So, I'd like to ask you to advise a very simple open source .net library that enables to create very simple 2D, keyframe based animations.

Or should I start from the scratch by timers...?

Thank you very much!

Comment: XNA is used mostly for 2D/3D games, and is a nice wrapper for directx. Directx is very complicated, OpenGL is more accessible, but still a little difficult. In WPF is relatively easy to create animations, you should try it.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://65.39.148.34/KB/miscctrl/CGAnimation.aspx?fid=159346&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=True&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2261416&fr=26)

Comment: If you need keyframe based - you want WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but I've heard this one is good:

http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/